# How does a download accelerator work?

Tags: download

What I want to know is how a download accelerator.Increases the download speed of the file you're downloading.Like when I am downloading a file without the download accelerator my download speed is 6.0-6.3 megabytes.But when using one my download speed is 6.7-6.8 megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach I've seen is requesting multiple parts of a file simultaneously and stitching the result back together.

The reasoning behind it would be that each single connection to the source server is limited in bandwidth. By opening several connections, you can possibly max out your own bandwidth.

Comment: Such programs also often use public mirror lists etc. to request different pieces from different sites/servers. Some can even request pieces from different networks, so you could end up simultaneously downloading from BitTorrent, eDonkey and so on besides HTTP/FTP.